# Test method not being run in results on running appium testing test on AWS Farm

Tags: android

I'm having the issue with my appium testNG tests to upload them  on AWS farm that I just get setup and teardown in results.  Why my instrumentation tests are not running? I have my tests starting like:
 public class DMAppium {
  WebDriver driver;

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() throws Exception {
  //before method content
    }

@AfterMethod
public void tearDown() throws Exception { 
    //After method content
}

@Test
public void Test() throws InterruptedException
{
```

//test method content
    }
}

And test script is running successfully in appium testng but But still just show teardown and setup suite tests in aws farm. Please help me with corrections.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.  I was able to figure out that if I uploaded my tests without the @beforeMethod annotation; my test would get picked up and actually run.  The opposite would happen when the annotation was included.

I'm just starting with TestNG, so I am not an expert; but here is a link that helped me out: [TestNG @BeforeMethod method not called when it resides in superclass and a specific group is run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020260/testng-beforemethod-method-not-called-when-it-resides-in-superclass-and-a-speci)

I think it has to do with not specifying beforeMethod as part of a group.

From the link:

> You can also use @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true) if you don't want to >hardcode the value of your group and if you think you will always want >to run this method, regardless of the group you are currently running.

I haven't quite figured out the xml configuration of groups with TestNG and AWS Device Farm; but this solved the issue for me.